# How to stop Visual Studio Code from autoformatting multiple selectors to new lines

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, autoformatting

Visual Studio Code's autoformatter keeps formatting multiple selector styling from this

```
.header-example, .header2-example {
  font-size: larger;
}
```

into this

```
.header-example,
.header2-example {
  font-size: larger;
}
```

How can I disable this? I don't want to turn off formatting on save, as that is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Settings -> Extensions -> CSS Language Features -> CSS" and deselect "Format: Newline Between Selectors"